# OpenGL shows black texture on quad

Tags: c++, opengl, stb-image

No matter what i try , i cant seem to make the quad show any textures, tried with solid color in the fragshader works fine, tried drawing the gradient tex coords worked fine .. as soon as i introduced  a sampler and tried setting the texture it wasnt working... attached some code and debugging details below
[image]

---

```cpp
int width, height, nrChannels;
bool hasAlpha;
unsigned int refID;

glGenTextures(1, &refID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, refID);

// set the texture wrapping/filtering options (on the currently bound texture object)

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


unsigned char* data = stbi_load("C:\\Users\\shubhz\\source\\repos\\Lumigen\\assets\\textures\\dia.png", & width, & height, & nrChannels, 0);

bool has_alpha = (nrChannels > 3) ? true : false;

if (data) {
    if (has_alpha)
        glTexImage2D(refID, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    else
        glTexImage2D(refID, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    Debug::log("Loaded Texture from :", " w: ", width, " h:", height, " alpha : ", has_alpha, "  refID ", refID);
}
else {
    //Failed to load texture
    Debug::log("Failed to load texture : ");
}

//frees up the tempdata after upload
stbi_image_free(data);

app.initialize();

glUseProgram(Resources::GetShader("default-shader"));
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, refID);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(Resources::GetShader("default-shader"), "texture1"), 0);
```

[image]

Drawing part:

```cpp
void SceneRenderer::render(Mesh& _mesh, Material& _mat, glm::mat4 _modelMatrix)
{
    glUseProgram(_mat.shader);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _mat.texture.refID);
    glBindVertexArray(_mesh.VAO);

    Shader::Mat4f(_mat.shader, "modelMatrix", _modelMatrix);
    Shader::Vec4f(_mat.shader, "_MainColor", glm::vec4(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.5f, 1));

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

}
```

Opened the application with render doc too, there was this weird error in the pipeline viewer showing invalid dimension in Base_level 0, but i logged the width and height they were fine

[image]

Comment: What's app.initialize() and where context is  created?

Comment: Context is created before the initial texture loading, app.initialize loads all the shader and other parameters for the app, i actually switched the texture loading here to isolate my error, otherwise it would go inside the app.initialize() call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to [`glTexImage2D()`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) is a texture `target` not the texture handle (in your case `refID`). So you need to replace `refID` with `GL_TEXTURE_2D`:

```c
if (has_alpha)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
else
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

This has most likely also produced errors, so this suggests that you're also not checking [`glGetError()`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetError.xhtml). You should at the very least check [`glGetError()`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetError.xhtml) (see [OpenGL Wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Error)).

Even better setup [Debug Output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output).

Check out [LearnOpenGL - Debugging](https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/Debugging) for more in-depth information about how to debug OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the problem.... and about debug output, itsn't availble before 4.3 so should i stick with glGetError?

Comment: Are you targeting macOS or simply targeting a lower OpenGL version? If it's the latter, then you can usually get away with using a newer version in debug builds, purely to be able to use debug output. Then use conditional compilation to disable it for release builds. At least this is what I've been doing for the last decade. Target 4.5 in debug build and then e.g. 3.3 in release build.

Comment: ah nice tip.. will keep in mind